# How do I select a character’s alternate color palette?

Tags: mario-kart-arcade-gp-dx

[According to the Super Mario Wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/index.php?title=Mario_Kart_Arcade_GP_DX&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop#Playable_characters), certain characters in *Mario Kart Arcade GP DX* have alternate color palettes.

> Characters are divided into five weight classes (feather, light, medium, cruiser, and heavy), ***with seven of these characters sporting alternate color swaps that allows them to access a special Item***.

The seven characters with alternate colors are Toad, Don-chan, Yoshi, Mario, Luigi, Bowser, and Metal Mario.

How do I select these alternate color palettes?